# How do I remove all interior paths in an Adobe Illustrator vector image?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector

I often want to simplify an illustration like the one on the left here to a solid shape with just the outer paths remaining. Is there a way to remove all interior paths within an Illustrator image? (I have provided a greatly simplified demonstration of what I mean.)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Select all
- Pathfinder Panel -> Unite Button

You *may* then need to chose `Object > Compound Path > Release` and hit the Unite button on the Pathfinder Panel again.